# XSLT formatting HTML Input

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am looking to use an XSLT to strip attributes out of an HTML file. The HTML file looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
        <title>CB Comfy Bike</title>
        <meta name="atg:string,index:$repositoryId" content="prod10005" />
        <meta name="atg:date:creationDate" content="955050507" />
        <meta name="atg:date:startDate" content="978325200" />
        <meta name="atg:date:endDate" content="1009861200" />
        <meta name="atg:string:$url"
            content="atgrep:/ProductCatalog/frame-product/prod10005?locale=en_US" />
        <meta name="atg:string,index:$baseUrl"
            content="atgrep:/ProductCatalog/frame-product/prod10005" />
        <meta name="atg:string:$repository.repositoryName" content="ProductCatalog" />
        <meta name="atg:string:$itemDescriptor.itemDescriptorName" content="frame-product" />
        <meta name="atg:string:childSKUs.$repositoryId" content="sku20007" />
        <meta name="atg:string:childSKUs.$itemDescriptor.itemDescriptorName" content="bike-sku" />
        <meta name="atg:date:childSKUs.creationDate" content="955068027" />
        <meta name="atg:float:childSKUs.listPrice" content="400.0" />
        <meta name="atg:float:childSKUs.salePrice" content="300.0" />
        <meta name="atg:boolean:childSKUs.onSale" content="false" />
        <meta name="atg:string:parentCategory.$repositoryId" content="cat55551" />
        <meta name="atg:date:parentCategory.creationDate" content="956950321" />
        <meta name="atg:string,docset:ancestorCategories.$repositoryId" content="cat10002" />
        <meta name="atg:string,docset:ancestorCategories.$repositoryId" content="cat10003" />
        <meta name="atg:string,docset:ancestorCategories.$repositoryId" content="cat55551" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="atg:role:displayName" id="0"> CB Comfy Bike </div>
        <div class="atg:role:longDescription" id="1"> This bike is just right, whether you are a
            commuter or want to explore the fire roads. The plush front suspension will smooth out
            the roughest bumps and the big disc brakes provide extra stopping power for those big
            downhills. </div>
        <div class="atg:role:keywords" id="2"> mountain_bike comfort_bike </div>
        <div class="atg:role:childSKUs.displayName" id="3"> CB Comfy Bike Medium </div>
        <div class="atg:role:childSKUs.listPrice" id="4"> 400.0 </div>
        <div class="atg:role:childSKUs.description" id="5"> Medium </div>
        <div class="atg:role:parentCategory.displayName" id="6"> Mountain Bikes </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am looking to at a new tag for each div, I have not focused on naming convensions yet, as it is proof of concept. However im not sure how to differenciate between div tags. This XSLT I have got so far is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="head"/>

    <xsl:template match="body">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="div/text()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<html>
    <body> CB Comfy Bike </body>
</html>
```

How would i turn the input into something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <tag1>CB Comfy Bike</tag1>
    <tag2>This bike is just right, whether you are a
        commuter or want to explore the fire roads. The plush front suspension will smooth out
        the roughest bumps and the big disc brakes provide extra stopping power for those big
        downhills.</tag2>
    <tag3>mountain_bike comfort_bike</tag3>
    <tag4>CB Comfy Bike Medium</tag4>
    <tag5>400.0</tag5>
    <tag6>Medium</tag6>
    <tag7>Mountain Bikes</tag7>
</root>
```

The trouble i have is differentiating between the Div tags.

Comment: Some (all?) XSLT processors may have issues processing arbitrary HTML. The main thing that comes to mind are the lack of many named entities in XML specification.

Can somebody correct me if I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This short and simple transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <root>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="body/div"/>
  </root>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="div">
  <xsl:element name="tag{position()}">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<html>
        <head>
            <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
            <title>CB Comfy Bike</title>
            <meta name="atg:string,index:$repositoryId" content="prod10005" />
            <meta name="atg:date:creationDate" content="955050507" />
            <meta name="atg:date:startDate" content="978325200" />
            <meta name="atg:date:endDate" content="1009861200" />
            <meta name="atg:string:$url"
                content="atgrep:/ProductCatalog/frame-product/prod10005?locale=en_US" />
            <meta name="atg:string,index:$baseUrl"
                content="atgrep:/ProductCatalog/frame-product/prod10005" />
            <meta name="atg:string:$repository.repositoryName" content="ProductCatalog" />
            <meta name="atg:string:$itemDescriptor.itemDescriptorName" content="frame-product" />
            <meta name="atg:string:childSKUs.$repositoryId" content="sku20007" />
            <meta name="atg:string:childSKUs.$itemDescriptor.itemDescriptorName" content="bike-sku" />
            <meta name="atg:date:childSKUs.creationDate" content="955068027" />
            <meta name="atg:float:childSKUs.listPrice" content="400.0" />
            <meta name="atg:float:childSKUs.salePrice" content="300.0" />
            <meta name="atg:boolean:childSKUs.onSale" content="false" />
            <meta name="atg:string:parentCategory.$repositoryId" content="cat55551" />
            <meta name="atg:date:parentCategory.creationDate" content="956950321" />
            <meta name="atg:string,docset:ancestorCategories.$repositoryId" content="cat10002" />
            <meta name="atg:string,docset:ancestorCategories.$repositoryId" content="cat10003" />
            <meta name="atg:string,docset:ancestorCategories.$repositoryId" content="cat55551" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="atg:role:displayName" id="0"> CB Comfy Bike </div>
            <div class="atg:role:longDescription" id="1"> This bike is just right, whether you are a
                commuter or want to explore the fire roads. The plush front suspension will smooth out
                the roughest bumps and the big disc brakes provide extra stopping power for those big
                downhills. </div>
            <div class="atg:role:keywords" id="2"> mountain_bike comfort_bike </div>
            <div class="atg:role:childSKUs.displayName" id="3"> CB Comfy Bike Medium </div>
            <div class="atg:role:childSKUs.listPrice" id="4"> 400.0 </div>
            <div class="atg:role:childSKUs.description" id="5"> Medium </div>
            <div class="atg:role:parentCategory.displayName" id="6"> Mountain Bikes </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<root>
   <tag1> CB Comfy Bike </tag1>
   <tag2> This bike is just right, whether you are a
                commuter or want to explore the fire roads. The plush front suspension will smooth out
                the roughest bumps and the big disc brakes provide extra stopping power for those big
                downhills. </tag2>
   <tag3> mountain_bike comfort_bike </tag3>
   <tag4> CB Comfy Bike Medium </tag4>
   <tag5> 400.0 </tag5>
   <tag6> Medium </tag6>
   <tag7> Mountain Bikes </tag7>
</root>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Appropriate use of templates.
2. Use of the **[`position()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-position)** function.
3. Use of **[AVT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates)** (Attribute Value Templates).

Comment: is there a way forgetting about position that i could pull just this tag ` <div class="atg:role:keywords" id="2"> mountain_bike comfort_bike </div>` for example. Could i use the class or id to pick only the tags i want. I bit like `<xsl:value-of select="div id=2/text()"/>`. I know this wont work, but it will hopefully give an idea as to what im asking.

Comment: @liveek: Of course one can select such text nodes using an XPath expression like: `/*/body/div[@id = 2]/text()` . So, you can replace the match pattern of the template (currently matching `div`) with `div[@id = 2]`. Your problem is that you don't seem to know what exactly you want and this shows in the question and in the fact that you have to clarify it in comments. The current question is fully answered. You can edit the question and make it more specific, or, better, you can ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Almost desired output )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="head"/>

  <xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:for-each select="div">
      <xsl:element name="{concat('tag', position())}">
        <xsl:value-of select="./text()"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: is there a way forgetting about position that i could pull just this tag ` <div class="atg:role:keywords" id="2"> mountain_bike comfort_bike </div>` for example. Could i use the class or id to pick only the tags i want. I bit like `<xsl:value-of select="div id=2/text()"/>`. I know this wont work, but it will hopefully give an idea as to what im asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something similar to Timur but I wouldn't use the for-each. I'd use a template to iterate over the div's within the body

Applying the following to the supplied XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="html">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="body"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="body">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="div"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div">
        <xsl:element name="{concat('tag', position())}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces the desired output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <tag1> CB Comfy Bike </tag1>
    <tag2> This bike is just right, whether you are a
        commuter or want to explore the fire roads. The plush front suspension will smooth out
        the roughest bumps and the big disc brakes provide extra stopping power for those big
        downhills. </tag2>
    <tag3> mountain_bike comfort_bike </tag3>
    <tag4> CB Comfy Bike Medium </tag4>
    <tag5> 400.0 </tag5>
    <tag6> Medium </tag6>
    <tag7> Mountain Bikes </tag7>
</root>
```

Use of:

1. Identity transform
2. attribute value template
3. apply-templates to iterate over child nodes

Comment: is there a way forgetting about position that i could pull just this tag ` <div class="atg:role:keywords" id="2"> mountain_bike comfort_bike </div>` for example. Could i use the class or id to pick only the tags i want. I bit like `<xsl:value-of select="div id=2/text()"/>`. I know this wont work, but it will hopefully give an idea as to what im asking.